# Is there a setting to make Firefox not directly download PDFs to Downloads when using "Open With"?

Tags: firefox, pdf, email, thunderbird, downloads

Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Possible culprits:

- Email client: Thunderbird
- PDF reader: Atril
- Browser: Firefox v. 104.0

None are snaps.

For years I've been getting a .pdf copy of a newspaper via links emailed to me. The emails are html formatted, and I click a field in them to download the paper.

Then a box pops up like this

[image]

giving me options. I always have chosen the "open with" option as shown.  Then the pdf opens in the viewer and all is well.

Except, at some point in the recent past, the .pdf has also started to get downloaded and saved in the Downloads directory. (I assume in the past it went into a temp directory, but I am sure that it didn't go into Downloads).

This also happens (but did not use to) when I click a link on website to open a .pdf This probably rules out Thunderbird as the culprit, now that I come to think about it.

In the course of my I day I look at a LOT of pdfs, many of which I don't care to save (and certainly not in Downloads) so I end up with a ton of cruft in Downloads that I have to manually delete.

Does anyone know what app made this change recently, and if there is a setting somewhere to prevent it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like Firefox stopped using temp directories for "open with" after version 98, because users were losing files, and they later added a config to get back this functionality: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1738574#c133

Go to `about:config` and set `browser.download.start_downloads_in_tmp_dir` to `true`, and restart Firefox, and it should use temp directories for "open with". Saving files works as intended.
Note that if you are using snap package, this might cause issues with temp folders.

Comment: What kind of "issues with temp folders" can be expected when using the snap package?

Comment: @Marijn for example, it doesn't download/openwith at all for me while using Firefox snap. Without this option, I couldn't save to `/tmp` with Firefox snap anyways.

Comment: @Cagri a major reason for avoiding snaps is that their permissions are so restricted they can't work properly if at all in `/tmp`.  What's unforgivably dumb about that is that the failure is either silent or cryptic, as I found out painfully slowly when `pdftk` stopped working as it should after updating my distro

Comment: This is exactly why I *hate* snap packages with a burning passion. They fail in unexpected ways, there is so much regression from the "normal" packages, and the fact that this is default and not opt-in means this is the experience normal users will have.