How can I stop Firefox from automatically saving a copy of files viewed with "Open with" in the Downloads folder?
I found this question about the same topic: Is there a setting to make Firefox not directly download PDFs to Downloads when using "Open With"?
A solution is given there but there is also a warning that "if you are using snap package, this might cause issues with temp folders". Apparently I am using a snap package because it says "Mozilla Firefox Snap for Ubuntu" in the About Firefox section.
So I am wondering if there is another solution which might work in my case?
I don't know anything about the difference between snap packages and other kinds of packages or whether you can actually choose between them, I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my desktop computer and 24.04 on my laptop and I am having the same problem on both machines. It wasn't a problem before on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine so I assume snap is something new that has been invented in the meantime.
Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions. Please explain things in detail as my technical knowledge and understanding is limited.

You are encountering this issue because Snap packages manage security for you. Mozilla uses a conservative, multi-layered security scheme to prevent a browser vulnerability from compromising your entire system. The Firefox Snap is denied access to ALL directories outside your /home. This includes denying access to /tmp directories that are deleted at each boot. Users cannot override this.
You have a few options:

You could file a request with Mozilla that they restore this feature in their Snap packages. Perhaps they might.

Technically knowledgeable users can create a "temporary" folder inside their /home directory, and create boot job to empty that directory. As you said that you are NOT skilled, I won't create a step-by-step guide; you won't be able to maintain it. You must learn how to to:

Create a directory
Change your Mozilla download setting to point to that directory
Create a systemd startup service (This is the hard part. Learn it first)


Another alternative for technically knowledgeable folks is to forego the Snap package and manage security yourself. Learn the skills to install Firefox using another method with less stringent security features, and learn how to keep it updated using that method. That also means learning how to mitigate and manage the risks yourself.



Thank you for your response, @user535733. Can you maybe elaborate on what you mean by "you won't be able to maintain it"? I know how to create a directory and how to change the settings in Firefox to make it download to another directory but I would indeed have to learn first how to create a systemd startup service. I am here to learn. But you seem to be saying that I may as well give it up or maybe that I should go somewhere else to learn?

Quite apart from that, it does not seem ideal to me for the default folder for (deliberate) downloads to be identical to the folder for temporary downloads (/tmp equivalent). Do you agree? Which would then leave me with solution no. 3 as probably the best alternative.

Most folks that write "Please explain things in detail as my technical knowledge and understanding is limited." aren't interested in learning, perhaps you are in the minority that is willing to learn new skills. Sure, if you learn the systemd skillls (not difficult), then you can indeed maintain it and #2 may be an appropriate option for you.

Whether you can separate .pdf downloads from deliberate downloads is a question that I do not know the answer to, and the input of others is welcome. Alternately, you might ask Mozilla that particular question,

That is an interesting observation. I only meant that I do not have any educational or professional background in computing and therefore I lack some basic understanding and knowledge compared to many others in here. I often read answers and comments which I don't quite understand (though I try very hard) and so I figured it might be wise to ask for detailed explanations from the outset. But clearly that was a mistake as it gave a wrong impression so I think I won't mention it next time and just ask for clarification along the way instead.

For the reasons mentioned before (of keeping wanted downloads separate from temporary ones), I think I will look for a way of converting from Firefox snap to Firefox deb as I think that must be what you meant with solution no. 3. I guess if only I can find the right .deb package, I can just download it, export my bookmarks, uninstall the snap package and then install the .deb package with apt install, can't I? I just don't want to end up having no browser.

There is something here: https://launchpad.net/%7Ephd/+archive/ubuntu/firefox/ but I am not quite sure what exactly to do.

@Thomas Covenant, I followed your link under the post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22 and I have a question: Is the snap package removed when performing the steps in the guide at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_install-firefox-deb-package-for-debian-based-distributions or do I need to do that additionally - and if so, at which point in the process?

I imagine it should be after copying the profile data and before installing the deb package but I am not quite sure since it is not menioned in the guide at all and the section on copying profile data is placed after explaining how to install. This has me a bit confused about the correct order of doing things.

I have now managed to install the deb package by following the instructions here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_install-firefox-deb-package-for-debian-based-distributions and subsequently change the settings as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429321/is-there-a-setting-to-make-firefox-not-directly-download-pdfs-to-downloads-when/1429330#1429330 Now as you said, I need to learn how to keep Firefox updated and managing security myself. Can you maybe give me a hint or somehow point me in the right direction?

I suggest opening a new question about how to monitor and keep the Firefox deb updated.

Thank you, @user535733, I have done so now. For those interested, the new question can be found at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525033/how-to-monitor-and-keep-the-firefox-deb-updated
